# Why Slime's debugger is not evaluating this specific expression in the selected frame?

Tags: debugging, common-lisp, break, stack-frame

I am trying to learn Common Lisp with the book *Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to Symbolic Computation*. In addition, I am using SBCL, Emacs, and Slime.

By the end of chapter 10, the author discuss the useful break function. In order to provide a background context, he presents this problematic function:

```
(defun analyze-profit (price commission-rate)
  (let* ((commission (* price commission-rate))
         (result
           (cond ((> commission 100) 'rich)
                 ((< commission 100) 'poor))))
    (format t "~&I predict you will be: ~S"
            result)
    result))
```

The function works as expected being called in REPL with arguments such as:

```
> (analyze-profit 1600 0.15)
I predict you will be: RICH
RICH

> (analyze-profit 3100 0.02)
I predict you will be: POOR
POOR
```

However, it shows a wrong result when `commission` is exactly 100:

```
> (analyze-profit 2000 0.05)
I predict you will be: NIL
NIL
```

In order to debug it, the author inserts the `break` function on the definition:

```
(defun analyze-profit-debugging (price commission-rate)
  (let* ((commission (* price commission-rate))
         (result
           (cond ((> commission 100) 'rich)
                 ((< commission 100) 'poor))))
    (break "Value of RESULT is ~S" result)
    (format t "~&I predict you will be: ~S"
            result)
    result))
```

Then he examines the **control stack** while checking the value of local variables:

[image]

I know debuggers are notoriously implementation dependent.

In my environment (emacs, slime, sbcl) I was able to reproduce something similar following this [great tutorial](https://lisp-journey.gitlab.io/blog/debugging-in-common-lisp/) writthen by @Vindarel.

After putting the point (cursor) on stack `0:` and pressing `e`:

```
Backtrace:
  0: (ANALYZE-PROFIT-DEBUGGING 2000 0.05)
  1: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (ANALYZE-PROFIT-DEBUGGING 2000 0.05) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  2: (EVAL (ANALYZE-PROFIT-DEBUGGING 2000 0.05))
```

I am able to evalue the expression in the stack frame. Thus, I get this messages on the **mini-buffer**:

```
Eval in frame (COMMON-LISP-USER)> price
=> 2000 (11 bits, #x7D0, #o3720, #b11111010000)
```

And:

```
Eval in frame (COMMON-LISP-USER)> commission-rate
=> 0.05
```

Unfortunately, I cannot access the main problem which is the `local variable` named `commission`:

```
Eval in frame (COMMON-LISP-USER)> commission
```

I was expecting:

```
100.0
```

But I get an error message:

> The variable COMMISSION is unbound.    [Condition of type
> UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

I double-check the spelling. In addition, I also tried using `p` instead of `e` and moving the cursor around. However, nothing worked.

How can I check the value of the problematic variable `commission`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you navigate to the top frame in the debugger and press enter on that frame, you will see that `commission` is not known to the debugger as a local variable:

```
Value of RESULT is NIL
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-CONDITION]

Restarts:
 0: [CONTINUE] Return from BREAK.
 1: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 2: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 3: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "new-repl-thread" RUNNING {1002D65C93}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (ANALYZE-PROFIT-DEBUGGING 2000 0.05)
      Locals:
        COMMISSION-RATE = 0.05
        PRICE = 2000
        RESULT = NIL
  1: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (ANALYZE-PROFIT-DEBUGGING 2000 0.05) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  2: (EVAL (ANALYZE-PROFIT-DEBUGGING 2000 0.05))
 --more--
```

The problem here is that the compiler has optimized away some debugging information. You can tell the compiler to include more debugging information with `declaim` at the beginning of the file, or `declare` in the function definition:

```lisp
(defun analyze-profit-debugging (price commission-rate)
  (declare (optimize (debug 3)))
  (let* ((commission (* price commission-rate))
         (result
           (cond ((> commission 100) 'rich)
                 ((< commission 100) 'poor))))
    (break "Value of RESULT is ~S" result)
    (format t "~&I predict you will be: ~S"
            result)
    result))
```

The number given to [`debug`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_optimi.htm) can be 0, 1, 2, or 3; a larger number means more emphasis should be placed on preserving debugging information.

Now in the debugger, pressing enter on the top stack frame shows the value of `commission` directly:

```
Backtrace:
  0: (ANALYZE-PROFIT-DEBUGGING 2000 0.05)
      Locals:
        COMMISSION = 100.0
        COMMISSION-RATE = 0.05
        PRICE = 2000
        RESULT = NIL
  1: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (ANALYZE-PROFIT-DEBUGGING 2000 0.05) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  2: (EVAL (ANALYZE-PROFIT-DEBUGGING 2000 0.05))
 --more--
```

And, using the `e` command on the top stack frame now works as you initially expected:

```
Eval in frame (COMMON-LISP-USER)> commission
=> 100.0
```